# jQuery: slide in content from right to left?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a simple content slideshow using jquery.

When i run my code, I get no sliding at all but at the same time I get no errors to indicate why my code doesn't work!

This is a working [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ykzwctoh/5/)

And this is my code:

```
$(window).load (function() {
    var theImage = $('.some');
    var theWidth = theImage.width()
    //wrap into mother div
    $('#feedTxt').wrap('<div id="mother" />');
    //assign height width and overflow hidden to mother
    $('#mother').css({
        width: function() {
        return theWidth;
      },
        height: function() {
        return theImage.height();
      },
        position: 'relative',
        overflow: 'hidden'
    });
        //get total of image sizes and set as width for ul
    var totalWidth = theImage.length * theWidth;
    $('#feedTxt').css({
        width: function(){
        return totalWidth;
    }
    });
});//doc ready
```

Could someone please advise on this issue?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

i now can go through the elements but they are not sliding really!!

here is another working [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ykzwctoh/12/)

Comment: Note you can add jQuery to your code by clicking the box in the top right-hand corner under the JavaScript section. Also don't use the load event, the code already runs on load.

Comment: Are you sure your code is running? Though looking at your code, I am wondering your reasoning behind this code method to create a slideshow?

Comment: @tnschmidt, i'm sure its running. its on jsfiddle! and yes, I'm trying to create a slideshow.

Comment: the JS isn't running in your jsfiddle. Try wrapping in `$(document).ready` instead of `$(window).load`.

Comment: @tnschmidt, EDITED my question with a new fiddle and code: https://jsfiddle.net/ykzwctoh/12/  the issue that I have now is that the contents do not slide in... they just jump in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this. The key here was adding `position:relative` to the parent `div` and making the slides `position:absolute;`.

```js
$("#feedTxt > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
  $('#feedTxt > div:first')
    .animate({width:'toggle'},350)
    .hide()
    .next()
    .animate({width:'toggle'},350)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#feedTxt');
},  3000);
```

```css
#feedTxt {
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    height:450px;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}

.some {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    height: 450px;
    position: absolute; 
    right: 0;
    top:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div align="center" id="feedTxt">

    <div class="some">
        <h1>title 1</h1>
        <br>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
            with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. </p>
    </div>



    <div class="some">
        <h1>title 2</h1>
        <br>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
            with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. </p>
    </div>


    <div class="some">
        <h1>title 3</h1>
        <br>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
            with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. </p>
    </div>


    <div class="some">
        <h1>title 4</h1>
        <br>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
            with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. </p>
    </div>


</div>
```